# Does somebody know more about the ALK Maps plugin for leaflet? I want to use their maps but i can't seem to find the api key

Tags: leaflet

I need to get the API key for ALK Maps plugin but i cant seem to find where to get it. Did somebody already use this plugin for leaflet or knows more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, ALK Technologies is now Trimble Maps

https://info.maps.trimble.com/get-an-api-key